# How can we retain authorship when we copy/paste a comment?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

We have comments in a Google Spreadsheet that were *not* originally written by us.
The cells the comments are written in already have "Conditional format rules" applied to them (e.g., cell H2).

[image: comment01]

We want to paste *just* the comments to other cells that they already have their "Conditional format rules" applied to them as well (e.g., cell H6).

---

When we try to copy/paste just the content of the comment, the authorship of the comment changes and appears as if we wrote the comment. We don't want that.

When we try to copy/paste the whole cell everything is pasted carrying along the "Conditional format rules" of the previous cell.
In addition, there is *not* an option to just paste the comment.

[image: comment02]

---

Do you know of a way to *just* paste the comment and retain the original authorship of the comment?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to copy comments, by design. Comments are not a part of spreadsheet's content, they are more like chat messages written _about_ its content and placed next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element shown in the screenshots is called Note. It could be added by using the Insert menu or a contextual menu.

The user interface doesn't include a command to paste only the note but [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) from the Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service include several methods to handle notes:

- getNote()
- getNotes()
- setNote(note)
- setNotes(notes)

The notes property type is string, in other words, it doesn't hold a link to the author profile or other complex information. If you don't want to create a script, just copy the content of the note, insert a new note and paste inside of it the content of the source note.

---

Google Sheets Insert Menu showing the insert note command.

[image: Google Sheets Insert menu]

Comment: You are so very right. :)