# Automated way to copy comments out of comment tool and paste into a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-comments

Ive got a spreadsheet with a load of "cell comments" using the comment tool.

I need to filter on these comments, which i understand i can not do.

My plan is to copy each of the comments out of the comment tool, and paste the contents of the comment into a blank cell in column P.

Is there an automated way i can do this ?

Comment: Ive also found this thread which touches on the same topic : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92664/how-can-we-retain-authorship-when-we-copy-paste-a-comment

Comment: Further helpful questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609953/get-cell-note-value

Comment: Are these notes or comments in your document? Comments are still not supported by Google Apps Script. There are open issues relating to them, see question linked. Only notes can be programmatically copied with Apps Script.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer These are comments not notes, it seems what i want to achieve can be done with notes, but not with comments

Comment: Yes, indeed! It seems to be impossible with Apps Script (at the moment) until Google solves the issues.
Not impossible in general. You could make a bot with Selenium :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time it's not possible by using Google Apps Script or the Google Drive API.

Reference

- [Provide read/write access to comments in Google Sheets](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650)

Related questions in Stack Overflow

- [Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Comment Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15556476/1595451)
- [Getting comments from range in Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18753147/1595451)
- [Count the number of comments on a particular worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33577254/1595451)
- [Creating anchored comments programmatically in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23498275/1595451)